# Enabling touch in ScrollViewer overrides drag behavior

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, touch, drag, scrollviewer

I have a WPF app that also runs on a tablet.  I have an ItemsControl that is wrapped in a ScrollViewer.

The items in the ItemsControl can be dragged and dropped into another area of the app.

When I enable PanningMode on the ScrollViewer, I can no longer drag the items.  It seems the touch for scrolling is overriding the touch for the drag.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a nice solution?

Edit: Drag was enabled on these controls with a MouseMove event which checks the MouseButtonState.

Edit2: I discovered the TouchDown and TouchMove events and added them to the controls.  But it still did not fix the problem.  With PanningMode=VerticalOnly, the Move events do not fire anymore.

Comment: Could you try something? <ScrollViewer PanningMode="VerticalOnly">

Comment: Actually that is my setting.  When I set PanningMode, the MouseMove and TouchMove events in the underlying controls aren't firing.